Reading the user emails using graph api and service principal
I am developing a usecase where I am developing a python program to read user emails from inbox and sentbox. Once the emails are extracted, I am to extract unique email ids from the extracted list of emails. The emails are to be extracted from Microsoft Email using Graph API
I am working with following key points:

The service prinicpal should only be able to access the data from the users who have provided consent to the application, basically user level access should be available to service principal and not the tenant level thus ensuring privacy.
The program should be parameterised i.e. user should requrie to provide consent only once. Once consent is provided, it's just that we have to add the email of the user to the list of users that we have.
The program should support full extraction(of emails) using pagination or delta/incremental extraction by providing custom time frames.
I cannot add the password of the users whose emails this program is going to extract.

Please help me with this usecase. I have tried few things but user level access is failing. The tenant level access works fine(which I don't want to implement since it is privacy breach as I can get anyone's emails).
I tried today and got the expected output using tenant level access, but failing to get it working with the user level access.
Here's the code I was using:
def get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json().get('access_token')

def get_all_emails_with_pagination(access_token, user_id):
    emails = []
    # url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages"
    # url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages?filter=isDraft ne true"
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/messages?filter=isDraft ne true"
    # url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?filter=isDraft ne true"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    while url:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad responses
        data = response.json()

        # Debug: Print the response data
        # print(f"Fetched {len(data.get('value', []))} emails.")

        # Extend the list with the current batch of emails
        emails.extend(data.get('value', []))
        
        # Check for the next page
        url = data.get('@odata.nextLink')  # Get the next page link

    return emails

tenant_id = 'placeholder'
client_id = 'placeholder'
client_secret = 'placeholder'
user_id = 'user@example.com
token = get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
# emails = get_user_emails(token, user_id)
emails = get_all_emails_with_pagination(token, user_id)

email_ids = [email['from']['emailAddress']['address'] for email 
in emails]

print(email_ids)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 9
      7 token = get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
      8 # emails = get_user_emails(token, user_id)
----> 9 emails = get_all_emails_with_pagination(token, user_id)
     12 # # Extract email IDs
     13 # email_ids = [email['from']['emailAddress']['address'] for email in emails]
     14 # print(email_ids)

Cell In[44], line 14
     12 while url:
     13     response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
---> 14     response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad responses
     15     data = response.json()
     17     # Debug: Print the response data
     18     # print(f"Fetched {len(data.get('value', []))} emails.")
     19 
     20     # Extend the list with the current batch of emails

File ~/miniconda3/envs/Snow/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/models.py:1024, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1019     http_error_msg = (
   1020         f"{self.status_code} Server Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
   1021     )
   1023 if http_error_msg:
-> 1024     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/messages?filter=isDraft%20ne%20true


Could you please edit your question and include more details like what code you tried,  and any error you faced?

In your code you have an invalid user_id which might be causing problems. `'user@example.com
token = get_access_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
emails = get_user_emails(token, user_id)
emails = get_all_emails_with_pagination(token, user_id)
email_ids = [email['`  is not a valid user email. And it's also very hard to memorize if you have to give your email to somebody. My suggestion is to fix it to a valid and more user friendly email

@user27548440 By running this code, which error message you got? Could you please share and edit the question?

@Cincinnatus, I have the correct email provided in the actual code, but since I am sharing it on the public portal I have removed all the critical values. Believe me it's correctly mapped in code at my end.

Ok, but then the instruction after setting the email_id seems incorrect: from']['emailAddress']['address'] for email in emails]  doesn't seem to be valid syntax. If this is also correct in your real code then you don't need to modify anything.  Then what would be left is just knowing what's you actual question. In order to provide answers people will need to know what are you actually asking

@Cincinnatus I am facing the error retrieving the data from the email. The flow is not reaching this part: email_ids = [email['from']['emailAddress']['address'] for email
in emails]

well as I mentioned it's not reaching this part because the user_id you posted here is incorrect and missing a closing '  but you mention that in your real code this is fine, so people will just ignore this error that you have here and assume that your code is fine. I have to assume the missing ' is not present in your code (which might or might not be the case)

@Cincinnatus Yes, the error is bad request error, but I have provided correct values and since I don't want to use admin level permission since it's a privacy risk, I am trying to use user delegated permission, but when using user delegated permission it's throwing the above error.

If it works with admin permission but it doesn't with tenant permissions then the error doesn't have to do with the code, but with the permissions. If you are the admin of the server, make tenants have permissions to execute the requests you need.

Do you have atleast Microsoft E3 license?

@PratikJadhav I am not sure since I am not the admin of the tenant.

@Cincinnatus Just to clarify admin permission grants access to tenant level resources i.e. access to every user's mailbox. I don't/can't want/get this level of access to the service principal. I want it to just be able to get the access to emails of users who have provided consent/access to the service principal.

Users might have provided consent but if the administrator of the server has not implemented that in the system there's no way you can access information that requires admin access with a plain user. If you need such feature request the administrator of the server to implement it.

@user27548440 You can check it under license section of particular user, CheckHere

@Cincinnatus we are using Azure Entra ID and don't have any specific server for same. Our usecase is using microsoft outlook and graph api all which is provided by microsoft and no server is setup by us for the same.

so against whom are you launching requests? There's a server running some code that somebody has to administer. And this code needs to allow tenants launch certain requests to access some information. Somebody own this server code and is the one who you should ask to implement that. It doesn't matter if the physical server is provided by Microsoft or if it's a raspberry pi above your router at home.

@PratikJadhav no E3 license for the user.

@user27548440 Can you share License blade screenshot?

You can scope App permission downs to certain mailboxes using an Application policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access. However this process needs to be done by an Admin and it can't be user driven like your asking.

The error occurred as you are calling /me endpoint with token generated with client credentials flow.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran the code in my environment with token generated with client credentials flow:

To resolve the error, switch to delegated flow like authorization code flow or interactive flow that generates token with signed-in user access level.
If you are trying to fetch emails from personal Microsoft account user, make sure to create app registration with below account type:

In my case, I used interactive flow for which public client option need to be enabled like this:

To extract unique email IDs from a list of emails retrieved from Microsoft Email using the Graph API, you can make use of below sample code:
import msal
import requests

CLIENT_ID = 'appId'
AUTHORITY = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
SCOPES = ['Mail.Read', 'User.Read']

def get_msal_app():
    return msal.PublicClientApplication(
        CLIENT_ID,
        authority=AUTHORITY
    )

def acquire_token_interactive(msal_app):
    result = msal_app.acquire_token_interactive(SCOPES)
    if 'access_token' in result:
        return result['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Could not acquire token: {result.get('error')}, {result.get('error_description')}")

def get_user_emails(access_token):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages'

    emails = []
    while graph_url:
        response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        emails.extend(data.get('value', []))
        graph_url = data.get('@odata.nextLink')

    return emails

def main():
    msal_app = get_msal_app()
    access_token = acquire_token_interactive(msal_app)

    emails = get_user_emails(access_token)
    email_ids = list(set([email['from']['emailAddress']['address'] for email in emails if 'from' in email]))
    print("Extracted Email IDs:")
    for email in email_ids:
        print(email)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Running above code will ask the user to sign in and gives below consent prompt once:

Output:

As tenant-level access is working for you, the only way is to switch to delegated flows for user level access. But that requires user to login at least once.
If you prefer making use of service principal authentication only by limiting access, you can create application access policy as suggested by @Glen Scales. Refer this similar SO thread.
